# Store data of one class in another class

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a class `fp` which represents a fixed point number. The underlying type is fixed at compile time, the position of the decimal point is determined at runtime.
Thus I need to store the position `p` of the decimal point somewhere.

Secondly, I want to use my fixed point number in structs which have variables of the fixed-point-number class `fp` type, including arrays of it ( NB: I am using Cuda, thus, I cannot use std::vector). Since storing the position `p` inside of the class `fp` would yield a large overhead, I would like to store it inside of the container structs.

E.g. something like the following (which clearly does not compile)

```
template<int &p_> struct fp {
    int data;
    float get() { return data/(float)p_; }
    void set( float data_ ) { data = data_*p_; }
};
struct container {
        int p = 4;
        fp<p> s;
};
```

I have the feeling that my approach is wrong, but I haven´t found another solution yet (I also have have no idea how to title my question --- feel free to edit it).

Comment: you can pass `p` as parameter to `get`

Comment: Would you want to have the same precision for *all* instances? You then might try a static member variable for your `fp` class (which then wouldn't remain a template any more).

Comment: @Aconcagua This would be my fallback option.

Comment: Hmm..., if the position is really only known at run-time, you should not use it as a template parameter, because a template parameter has to be a constexpr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fp` is tied really closely to `container`. I'd make that really explicit, and make `fp` a nested type of `container`. In C++, nesting a type does not create a special relation between *instances*. That relation between `container` and `fp` instances remains the member `fp container::s`.

But you can now write `container` accessors that wrap `fp::get()`, adding `fp::d` to the argument list of `get`.

[edit]
Since we'd need this in multiple classes, time for a bit of CRTP.

```
template <typename CT>
class baseContainer 
{
protected:
   struct fp {
     int data;
     float get(int p_) const { return data/(float)p_; }
     void set( float data_, int p_ ) { data = data_*p_; }
  };
  float get(fp const& fp_) { return fp_.get((CT const*)(this)->p_); }
  void set( fp& fp_, float data_) { fp.set(data, (CT*)(this)->p_); }
}
```

Now `container` can inherit from `baseContainer<container>`. In `baseContainer<container>`, `(CT*)(this)->p_` refers to `container::p_`.

Comment: The struct `container` is not the only place where I want to use it. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I am not that fit with CRTP at the moment and do not get this example to work. Could you elaborate a bit more on it. In particular, also write code how to use it?

Comment: @tommsch: The idea of CRTP is that a class can inherit from a class template that's instantiated using the derived class as a template argument, i.e. `class container : public baseContainer<container> { ... }`. Therefore, inside the methods of `baseContainer<container>` you know that `this` is really a `container*` and that there must be a `container::p_` member.